Unable to use itemize inside multicolumn using tabulary
I am using the tabulary package to create tables (unable to use other table packages because tabulary has been used everywhere else in the document). But for some reason I am unable to put a list inside a multicolumn. Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
The following is random text for checking table containing itemize with multicolumn
\\ 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|p{4cm}|p{6.5cm}|p{6cm}|}
 \hline
   Text in col1 
& 
\begin{itemize}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
\end{itemize}
& Text in col 3.  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{
   \begin{itemize}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
\end{itemize}
}\\ \hline

\end{tabulary}
\end{center}
\end{document}

Itemize works fine in the regular column but not inside multicolumn. The error is:
Runaway argument? { \begin {itemize} \item item 1 \item item 2 \end {itemize} 
! Paragraph ended before \multicolumn was complete.

What am I doing wrong?

Runaway argument? means you miss a closing curly brackets somewhere. As to your problem, lists are only allowed inside paragraph cells, e.g. the one created by p{} column type, which you can also use with \multicolumn. This is table has other issues but that is an answer for this question.
